# Remove the whole div structure by clicking on <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have around 100 icons and when i select some of them, they appear in the following div blocks:

[image]

Here's how i generate the structure above:

```
$(this).addClass("active");

   str += '<div class="liveicon" id="'+id+'" dtype = "'+type+'" dclss="'+clss+'" dattr="'+attr+'">';
   str += '<span class="close-icon" id="close-icon">&#10006;</span>';
   str += '<span id="'+id+'" dtype = "'+type+'" dclss="'+clss+'" dattr="'+attr+'" class=" anyi '+clss+'"></span>';
   str += '<div class="clearboth"></div>';
   str += '<div class="codes">';
   str += '<div class="tit">FONT</div><input type="text" class="fontsc" value="[anyicon i=\''+clss+'\' '+stylestr+']">';
   str += '<div class="tit">PNG</div><input type="text" class="pngsc" value="[anyicon i=\''+clss+'\' '+stylestr+' type=\'png\']">';
   str += '<div class="tit">SVG</div><input type="text" class="svgsc" value="[anyicon i=\''+clss+'\' '+stylestr+' type=\'svg\']">';
   str += '</div>';
   str += '</div>';

  $(".selected .content").append(str);
```

I want to add a link to the close icon, which is a span class, so after clicking to remove the related icon. I've tried with adding `<a href="#"></a>` and then handling with js, but it's not the right way. Any ideas are welcome.
Here's the whole Js file for easily orientate:

```
$(document).on('click', ".loadarea .content .anyicons .anyi", function () {
        //$(".anyicon .anyi").on('click', function(e) {
            var type = $(this).attr("dtype");
            var clss = $(this).attr("dclss");
            var attr = $(this).attr("dattr");
            var id = type+''+clss;
            //console.log(type);
            var str = "";
            var style = $("#anyicon_styles").val();
            var stylestr = "style=\''+style+'\'";
            if(style == "0"){ style = ""; stylestr = ""; }

            if($(this).hasClass("active")){
                $(this).removeClass("active");
                $(".selected .content .liveicon#"+id).remove();
                loadLibraryMsg();

            } else {
                $(this).addClass("active");

                str += '<div class="liveicon" id="'+id+'" dtype = "'+type+'" dclss="'+clss+'" dattr="'+attr+'">';
                str += '<span class="close-icon" id="close-icon">&#10006;</span>';
                str += '<span id="'+id+'" dtype = "'+type+'" dclss="'+clss+'" dattr="'+attr+'" class=" anyi '+clss+'"></span>';
                str += '<div class="clearboth"></div>';
                str += '<div class="codes">';
                str += '<div class="tit">FONT</div><input type="text" class="fontsc" value="[anyicon i=\''+clss+'\' '+stylestr+']">';
                str += '<div class="tit">PNG</div><input type="text" class="pngsc" value="[anyicon i=\''+clss+'\' '+stylestr+' type=\'png\']">';
                str += '<div class="tit">SVG</div><input type="text" class="svgsc" value="[anyicon i=\''+clss+'\' '+stylestr+' type=\'svg\']">';
                str += '</div>';
                str += '</div>';

                $(".selected .content").append(str);

                loadLibraryMsg();
            }
        });
```

p.s If you think am not asking a good question, please send me tutorials how it can be done, it would help a lot. Thanks in advance

Comment: so what you want?

Comment: When i click on the close icon, to remove the related block.

Comment: Why can't you put that span inside anchor tag like this:
<a href="somelink"><span class="close-icon" id="close-icon">&#10006;</span></a>
If you want to call some js function on clicking <a> tag use this:
<a href="functionName()"><span class="close-icon" id="close-icon">&#10006;</span></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):-

```
$(".selected .content").on('click','.close-icon',function(){
  $(this).closest('.liveicon').remove();
});
```

If not worked then try this one:-

```
$(document).on('click','.close-icon',function(){
  $(this).closest('.liveicon').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By this Example you will get the help :

```js
$('span').click(function(){
 $(this).closest('.parent').remove();
})
```

```css
.parent{
  position:relative;
  width:70%;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
  width:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
}
span{
  position:absolute;
  right:2%;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSd8cAJmOsrWimMAMpTAFOPURbw4q7uDKKxau1nimZ4V-usMb0w'/>
  <span>X</span>
</div>
```